# How to use javascript' if in html?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
<script>
  function checklistParser(block){
    return (
      '<div class="ce-block">' +
        '<div class="ce-block__content">' +
          '<div class="cdx-block cdx-checklist">' +
            block.data.items.map((item) => (
              '<div class="cdx-checklist__item '`${item.checked}` ? 'cdx-checklist__item--checked' : '' ' ">' +
                '<span class="cdx-checklist__item-checkbox">' +
                '</span>' +
                '<div class="cdx-checklist__item-text">' +
                  item.text +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>'
            )).join('') +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>'
    );
  }
</script>
```

---

What I'm trying to do is that if `item.checked = true`,

I want to add class `cdx-checklist__item--checked` but I got stuck in this.

---

I got this error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: `\`${item.checked}\` ? 'cdx-checklist__item--checked' : ''` -> `+ \`${item.checked ? 'cdx-checklist__item--checked' : ''}\` +`

Comment: Check the syntax for string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

To make this easier to read you could make more use of template literals (ES6). Then you can avoid issues with string concatenation?

```
function checklistParser(block) {
  return (
    `<div class="ce-block">
      <div class="ce-block__content">
        <div class="cdx-block cdx-checklist">
          ${block.data.items.map((item) => (
            `<div class="cdx-checklist__item ${item.checked ? `cdx-checklist__item--checked` : ``}">
               <span class="cdx-checklist__item-checkbox"></span>
               <div class="cdx-checklist__item-text">${item.text}</div>
            </div>`
          )).join('')}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line

```
'<div class="cdx-checklist__item '`${item.checked}` ? 'cdx-checklist__item--checked' : '' ' ">'
```

to

```
`<div class="cdx-checklist__item ${item.checked ? 'cdx-checklist__item--checked' : ''}">`
```

note that the difference is to use template literal `` to enclose whole line, and put the conditional (ternary) operator inside `${}`

```js
  function checklistParser(block){
    return (
      '<div class="ce-block">' +
        '<div class="ce-block__content">' +
          '<div class="cdx-block cdx-checklist">' +
            block.data.items.map((item) => (
              `<div class="cdx-checklist__item ${item.checked ? 'cdx-checklist__item--checked' : ''}">` +
                '<span class="cdx-checklist__item-checkbox">' +
                '</span>' +
                '<div class="cdx-checklist__item-text">' +
                  item.text +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>'
            )).join('') +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>'
    );
  }
  
 var block = {
  data: {
   items:[{checked: true}]
  }
 } 
  
 console.log(checklistParser(block));
```